The organization of the working class and labour market regulation in Lord Keynes general theory
I am reading the book "Fundamentals of the General Theory. The theoretical consequences of Lord Keynes, by Axel Kicillof, and in chapter IV, that speaks of the transformations of the working class, argues that the postulates of the classics in relation to market forces reaching a level of equilibrium between the supply and demand of labour in the market cannot be applied. based on the marginal disutility of labour and the marginal utility of wages, since workers organized in unions represent a distortion of the market. However, the question arises whether we cannot consider workers' organizations, the unions, as actors in the market and that in an organized way represent the workers and their assessments of the level of marginal disutility of labour. In other words, it would be the same as what the classics propose, but now instead of considering workers in the market in an atomized way, we would consider them in an organized way, and then the actor to be taken into account would no longer be the individual workers, but the union.
Please, let me know if I’m wrong.
